# How to close the currently active window using cmd or batch command in windows 10?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm looking for a command that can close the currently active window or running application in windows 10. I know taskkill but this is different because here you can't specify the name of the active window/running application. How should I go about this? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't as easy as it sounds.  You would need a program that would find the topmost window and close that task.. and it would need to be smart about it.. I am aware of no such program.  If the thing 'on top' is always the same.. that would make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I just wanted to close the command window automatically after exiting the game. I just double click on the .bat file on my desktop. No shortcuts.

```
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
C:\"GOG Games"\Starcraft\Starcraft.exe
start explorer.exe
exit /B
```

Comment: Here's my situation: I got a .bat file on a scheduler it runs every 9PM everyday, what it does is it opens a URL from YouTube and plays the video in fullscreen (no problem here I got this). The problem is when there's an active window or a running application like Netflix the .bat file still works but it plays on the background instead of overriding whatever is active on my screen. What I want to achieve here is to override whatever is playing or active on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
C:\Program Files\nircmd-x64\nircmd.exe" win min process xxx.exe
```

followed by

```
C:\Program Files\nircmd-x64\nircmd.exe" win max process yyy.exe
```